# Property of real injective functions

Tags: functions, inequality

Let $f$ be a real injective function. Prove that there exists $x$ such that $f(x^2)-(f(x))^2 < 1/4$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose that for every $x$ we have $$f(x^2)-f(x)^2 \geq \frac{1}{4}$$

The trick is to use an $x$ such that $x^2=x$ so let's plug $x=0$ and $x=1$ :

$$f(0)-f(0)^2 \geq \frac{1}{4}$$

$$\left ( f(0)-\frac{1}{2} \right )^2 \leq 0$$ so $f(0)=\frac{1}{2}$

In an analogue manner we can get $f(1)=\frac{1}{2}$ which contradicts the fact that $f$ is injective .

Comment: But wouldn't you get f(0)≤1/2 ?

Comment: The squares are always positive : $x^2 \geq 0$ for every $x$ so because $\left (f(0)-\frac{1}{2} \right )^2 \leq 0$ and is also $\geq 0$ it must be exactly $0$ . This means that $f(0)=\frac{1}{2}$ .